# Parsing Noun phrases from a parsed text using C/C++

Tags: c++, c, parsing, text

I want to parse the noun phrases (NN,NNP,NNS,NNPS) from a parsed text. E.g.:

```
Input sentence -
John/NNP
works/VBZ
in/IN
oil/NN
industry/NN
./.
Output: John Oil Industry
```

I am confused about the logic as I need to search for strings such as `/NN`, `/NNP`, `/NNS` and `/NNPS` and print the previous word before it. 
What will be the logic to parse the noun phrases using either C or C++?

My own try was the following:

```
char* SplitString(char* str, char sep 
{
    return str;
}
main()
{
    char* input = "John/NNP works/VBZ in/IN oil/NN industry/NN ./.";
    char *output, *temp;
    char * field;
    char sep = '/NNP';
    int cnt = 1;
    output = SplitString(input, sep);

    field = output;
    for(temp = field; *temp; ++temp){ 
       if (*temp == sep){
          printf(" %.*s\n", temp-field, field);
          field = temp+1;
       }
    }
    printf("%.*s\n", temp-field, field);
}
```

My modification is the following:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::string s = "John/NNP works/VBZ in/IN oil/NNS industry/NNPS ./.";
    std::regex rgx("(\\w+)\/NN[P-S]{0,2}");
    std::smatch match;

    if (std::regex_search(s.begin(), s.end(), match, rgx))
        std::cout << " " << match[1] << '\n';
}
```

The output I am getting is only "John". Other /NNS tag is not coming.

My second approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

char** str_split(char* a_str, const char a_delim)
{
    char** result = 0;
    size_t count = 0;
    char* tmp = a_str;
    char* last_comma = 0;
    char delim[2];
    delim[0] = a_delim;
    delim[1] = 0;

    /* Count how many elements will be extracted. */
    while (*tmp)
    {
        if (a_delim == *tmp)
        {
            count++;
            last_comma = tmp;
        }
        tmp++;
    }

    /* Add space for trailing token. */
    count += last_comma < (a_str + strlen(a_str) - 1);

    /* Add space for terminating null string so caller
       knows where the list of returned strings ends. */
    count++;

    result = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);

    if (result)
    {
        size_t idx  = 0;
        char* token = strtok(a_str, delim);

        while (token)
        {
            assert(idx < count);
            *(result + idx++) = strdup(token);
            token = strtok(0, delim);
        }
        assert(idx == count - 1);
        *(result + idx) = 0;
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char text[] = "John/NNP works/VBZ in/IN oil/NN industry/NN ./.";
    char** tokens;

    //printf("INPUT SENTENCE=[%s]\n\n", text);

    tokens = str_split(text, '');

    if (tokens)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; *(tokens + i); i++)
        {
            printf("[%s]\n", *(tokens + i));
            free(*(tokens + i));
        }
        printf("\n");
        free(tokens);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output with that is:

```
[John/NNP]
[works/VBZ]
[in/IN]
[oil/NN]
[industry/NN]
[./.]
```

I want only `/NNP` and `/NN` parsed data i.e. `John`, `oil` and `industry`. How to get this? Will regex help? How to use regex in C same as C++?

Comment: I am confused with the logic. I am trying to search for strings such as /NN, /NNP, /NNS and /NNPS and then printing all the characters before "/" till it gets a whitespace.

Comment: @New_Programmer that should about work.

Comment: @Haris No it's not called Natural Language Processing. Its a simple parsing problem.

Comment: @Identity1 - Can you please say where I am getting wrong ?

Comment: @New_Programmer try to define an algorithm for SplitString this may take some time and brain then ask us

Comment: @New_Programmer does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lines to "Add space for trailing token" are unnecessary, as `strtok` will automatically end at the terminating zero.

Also, `tokens = str_split(text, '');` cannot be correct, as your `str_split` expects a character for `a_delim`, and you feed it with `''`, which on my compiler (Clang) issues the error

```
error: empty character constant
```

Presumably you meant to split on a single space `' '`, but I did not test if that in itself would work. (Even though you get some form of output anyway.)

Your code returns the result `[John/NNP]` (etc.) because you don't do anything else to split off the tag name, and also you don't test against your wish-list of tags. A C program only does what you tell it to – that is what programming is for.

---

I propose a straightforward solution in plain C, using the string tokenizing function [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok), single char lookup [`strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr), and string comparison [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) only.

My routine *tokenizes* the input string on spaces, splitting off one word at a time on the spaces (note: for this to work, `strtok` needs to be able to modify the input string), *locates* the slash in this token, *compares* the text after the slash against a list of desired phrases, and *outputs* the word before the slash if it is in the list.

1. After each `strtok` call, the pointer `token` will point to the start of the next word, which already will be zero-terminated. Thus, the first token will be `John/NNP`.
2. Then `strchr` attempts to find the slash, and if found, will put its location into `slash`.
3. If it succeeds, `slash` points to the slash itself; so, the test tag should be at `slash+1`.
4. A simple loop compares this against each tag name in the `wanted` list. If it is found, `*slash` is set to `0`, overwriting the slash, so the current token string ends right before it. It then outputs the current token.
5. Whether found or not, `strtok` is called again in a loop until it fails. If it successfully locates a next token, it rolls back to #2, and exits otherwise.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    /* input */
    char text[] = "John/NNP works/VBZ in/IN oil/NN industry/NN ./.";
    char *wanted[] = { "NN", "NNP", "NNS", "NNPS" };

    /* helper variables */
    size_t i;
    char *token, *slash;

    token = strtok(text, " ");
    while (token)
    {
        slash = strchr (token, '/');
        if (slash && slash[1])
        {
            for (i=0; i<sizeof(wanted)/sizeof(wanted[0]); i++)
            {
                if (!strcmp (slash+1, wanted[i]))
                {
                    *slash = 0;
                    printf ("%s\n", token);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output of this program:

```
John
oil
industry
```

I did not bother to capitalize the words as per your desired output. It is a trivial addendum and you should be able to work out that much by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If its all about printing then try this approach. Its using a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) in the search function to find if there is a pattern  `\/NN[A-Z]{0,3}` that is /NN followed by 0 to 3 capital letters and captures `()` the `\\w+` word before it.

This is untested though:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::string s = "John/NNP works/VBZ in/IN oil/NN industry/NN ./.";
    std::regex rgx("(\\w+)\/NN[A-Z]{0,3}");
    std::smatch match;

    while (std::regex_search(s, match, rgx))
        std::cout << "match: " << match[1] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: 1: It is only showing "John" as output. I am trying to parse all four /NNP, /NN, /NNS and /NNPS type of noun phrase. Anyways thanks for the code snippet. I got the idea. Let me continue trying. Thanks.

Comment: While loop is printing "John" in a loop.

Comment: Yeah I haven't done regex in CPP before so not sure how to make the scope global

Answer (score 0):

regex_token_iterator may be of help

```
   std::string input = "John/NNP works/VBZ in/IN oil/NN industry/NN ABC/NNPS ./.";

   // This regex has a capture group () that is looking for a sequence of word characters
   // followed by /NN which is not captured but just matched
   std::regex nouns_re("(\\w+)\\/NN");

   // We pass 1 as the final argument to the token iterator 
   // because we just want to print the word captured and not the /NN part
   std::copy( std::sregex_token_iterator(input.begin(), input.end(), nouns_re, 1),
              std::sregex_token_iterator(),
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n")
        );
```